# How to show text in desired position in Subtitle View in Exoplayer

Tags: java, xml, exoplayer

I am new to android studio. I am trying to customize exoplayer UI, and able to show the player view and play controls where I want by the following code. But the text in subtitle view is always at the bottom of the view port. How to place subtitle text in a desired position, such as center, or top in subtitle view?

I've tried to use different xml layout, such as limiting the height of the subtitle view, but it seems that the subtitle view will occupy all the space below the player view. I also read the subtitle view class documentation to find methods to achieve what is desired, but no success.Thanks for help in advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
android:id="@+id/Navigator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Test1"
android:textAllCaps="false" />

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout 
    android:id="@id/exo_content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center">

    <!-- Video surface will be inserted as the first child of the content 
    frame. -->

    <View android:id="@id/exo_shutter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <View
        android:id="@id/exo_controller_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView 
    android:id="@id/exo_subtitles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the screenshot of the player on emulator :**

[image]

Comment: i did this with array having a string value and a color resource. somewhat it is working good. but what i did is completely customized. may be exoplayer have some default functions for that.